# How to add multiple event delegation in jquery with focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute two events with one "on" function. I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="lesson" />

$('#lesson').on("focusout keyup",function(e){
    var $change_education = $(this);
    if(e.which === 188){
       var current_value = $(this).val();
       add_edit_tags(current_value, $change_education);
    }
});
```

The keyup event is working but the focusout is not. I can't see anything from the web how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: what is the `lesson` element type also you are checking for `e.which` which will not be set if it is a focusout

Comment: an input type. see my edit

Comment: @comebal It matters because `focusout` isn't fired for all elements.

Comment: so what am I going to change focusout with? @alex

Comment: @comebal The code is correct and it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are checking for `e.which === 188` which will not be set if it is a `focusout` event, change the condition as below and check

```
$('#lesson').on("focusout keyup",function(e){
    var $change_education = $(this);
    if(e.type == 'focusout' || e.which === 188){
       var current_value = $change_education.val();
       add_edit_tags(current_value, $change_education);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZwWYE/)